# How is this plugin designed to crash IE6, crashing IE6?

Tags: jquery, browser, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-6, crash

[Chad Smith](http://twitter.com/chadsmith) came out with a [jQuery plugin designed to crash the IE6 browser](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/crash).

```
;jQuery.crash=function(x){for(x in document.open);};
```

What is this doing exactly to cause the problem?

Comment: This is awesome BTW.  Looks pretty easy.

Comment: Meh.  `practicalApplication = fail;`

Comment: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/6-html-and-javascript-codes-to-crash-ie6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't opening windows, it's trying to iterate over the `document.open` object.  Some native code property in there causes IE6 to crash.

Here's an example of what would be in there if it worked (try on any non-IE6 browser):

http://jsfiddle.net/XB8j8/

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't have anything at all to do with JQuery from what I see.

```
<body onload='for(x in document.open);'>
```

It looks to open up an infinite number of windows, therefore, running you out of memory, causing IE to crash.